# Help identify this poster of early 1900's movie with a woman sitting on a bench and a man behind holding her arm

Tags: identification, movies

I'm trying to identify the movie of this poster in the front of a movie theater from a picture dated <s>1904</s> 1917.

[image: movie theater 1917 - rio grande do sul]

It depicts what looks like a woman sitting on a bench in a white dress, and a man behind holding her arm. Firstly I thought she was fainting, but looking better, there is a bench behind her, she looks up to the right in the direction of the man. He seems standing up looking down towards her. Maybe a vampire? Maybe they are dancing? Unfortunately the resolution won't help.
The sign also partially reads ?ANTIFE(M)?.
The language is probably Portuguese, Italian or maybe French.

[image: a woman sitting on a bench in a white dress, and a man behind holding her arm]

*[photo from caxiaspormancuso](https://caxiaspormancuso.blogspot.com/2013/08/caxias-1904-1910-fotos-historicas-de.html)*

I know there was not many movies around back then.
Does anyone have a clue what movie is that?

I don't know the genre of this movie, but it's probably a movie. Because it is a movie theater (the object of my research is this theater) and the sign below reads HOJE, that means "Today" in Portuguese (thanks @NJohnny).
I thought I could be fantastical because of the pose of the characters and many movies back then used be fantastical, and there are children at the door, it looks like a vampire to me. But I might be wrong.

In the title I try to describe the image to avoid the use of "this photo" and improve it's searchability.

---

@Richard suggested it could be [Faust and Marguerite by Mellies](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0895/0864/products/lc120312__0165_1_600x.jpg?v=1483613118)
[image]

But they are in a different position than in that picture.

There is a letter in the front of the mystery word "ANTIFEM". @NJohnny suggested (P R V W). To me it looks like a "K", but at least in Portuguese that would make no sense. This also could be an "A", or less probably, "O" as this is "The" in Portuguese. Looks like there is a small gap between this letter and the next word, indicating this might be a "the". (The antifem...).
"Antifemale" was suggested, but to me it looks like a weird subject for a <s>116</s> 103 year movie, and if so, the title would be smaller than the space in the poster.

Comment: Faust and Marguerite (Melies) was released in 1904. The classical depiction has him standing behind her, vampire-like; https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0895/0864/products/lc120312__0165_1_600x.jpg?v=1483613118.

Comment: @gst - In the early 1900s, it would have been common for a film to play for weeks and for there to be hand-painted bills and murals rather than pre-printed posters

Comment: I've found a higher quality photo here https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-dZvXeczee-s/VXmoZk1op4I/AAAAAAAAunU/HpzQHt0_LEE/s1600/MAN%2B010%2B%255BA5356%255D.jpg. The picture is of a young lady sitting on a bench. The text underneath read *P(?)ANTIFEM????*

Comment: note that in portuguese 'A' is also 'the', but feminine. If it is such article, at least we know that it is singular, as the plural forms would be 'os' or 'as'

Comment: A possibility: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0930761/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1  The title, from 1917, is "Anana antiféministe". Which could have been translated as "A Antifeminista". I think the number of letters fits well in the presumed space.

Comment: The names of the photo author and keeper, in red, top of the higher quality version are certainly portuguese or spanish, not french. Autoria (authorship) and acervo (more or less 'collection') are also Portuguese. "Funilaria" today means in Brazil a place where you can fix broken car parts, specially the metal plates. I have no idea what it would mean in 1910 Portugal.

Comment: https://caxiaspormancuso.blogspot.com/2014/06/vista-da-fachada-dopredio-onde.html Here the webpage from the family of the original photographer, it is Brazil, not Portugal. If it is "A antifeminste", them the 1904 date is wrong.

Comment: @Luiz the word "funilaria", at least in this region, is still used for workshops that makes metal rain gutters and other works with thin metal plates.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure about the movie, but here is the web page of [family of the original photographer](https://caxiaspormancuso.blogspot.com/2014/06/vista-da-fachada-dopredio-onde.html), and [their version of your image](https://caxiaspormancuso.blogspot.com/2014/06/vista-da-fachada-dopredio-onde.html)

It is a cinema at Caxias do Sul, Rio Grande do Sul, Brasil.

Certainly it makes sense that the word at the bottom of the poster is HOJE (today).
The webpage dates the picture to 1904, but, if you accept that the date may be wrong, I have a possibility about the movie title.

[Anana Antiféministe](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0930761/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt), a French movie from 1917, might have been translated as "A ANTIFEMINISTA". The number of letters appear to fit well in the presumed space.

About the first letter, in Portuguese, "the" may be translated as "o", "a", "os", or "as". 'o' - male form, 'a' - female form, and the 's' means plural.

About the date, [his bio](https://caxiaspormancuso.blogspot.com/2015/08/domingos-mancuso.html) says that in 1904 his older brother moved to Caxias for medical treatment (due to the better climate), and then he also moved to help his brother. And "*A partir de então já começou a produzir fotografias*" - "from this time he already started to produce photos"

It means, that if it is from 1904, it must be one of his first professional photos ever.

Comment: Great!! and that fits in the poster.. And yes I found that as 1904, but they might be wrong. One thing to notice is that the building on the right shows 1893, but it looks too worn out for just eleven years. But I would never imagined a movie that old would have this subject!!! Thank you!

Comment: Just want to share two interesting developments this question has brought up. One is the fact that this photo was incorrectly dated. The second is that it seems that this movie is lost. I could not find a single poster, image, and nor even pictures of the main actors. So maybe this poster in the picture is everything that is left from this movie...

Comment: yesterday I had found this: http://www.cineartistes.com/fiche-Pierre+Etchepare.html At least you have a face

Comment: https://peoplepill.com/people/suzanne-le-bret/gallery/ And Suzanne